# Microservice design to fetch different DBs according to parameter

Tags: microservices

I'm facing a scenario where I have a microservice that fetches possible filter values as the user is typing a query. Ex.: As the user type "`city:`", the possible values that could come is: `Rio de Janeiro`, `New York` and etc. And the possible values comes from a variety of databases or even other microservices, each filter could have its own database to be fetched.

I'm thinking about something like the image below.

[image]

How can I build something like this?

Comment: Why do you have severeal distinct "filter databases"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `CQRS` behavior to hold the filtered possibilities within the primary service and sync it on sub-service/db changes.

You may search it online and also check [cqrs implementation for C#](https://github.com/saturn72/cloud-design-patterns/tree/main/cqrs)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion strategy pattern does not fit since it is aimed to change behaviour indistinctly. But the parameters could change and don’t make sense to follow the same request format(for example one could be get , other post, n number of parameters, etc)
I guess you should work on designing a reverse proxy which can map different kind of request to different micro services inside your app world